Reformulate constraints
I have the following constraints and am wondering whether I can formulate the whole thing more narrowly and with fewer constraints. $x_{itk}$ is binary and $u_{it}, v_{itk}\in [0,1]$. $M$ is a Big-M constant.
These are my constraints.
\begin{align}
&v_{itk} \geq u_{it} - M\cdot (1-x_{itk})& \forall i \in I, t\in T, k\in K \\
            &v_{itk} \leq u_{it} + M\cdot (1-x_{itk})& \forall i \in I, t\in T, k\in K\\
            &v_{itk} \leq x_{itk}& \forall i \in I, t\in T, k\in K
\end{align}

Does this answer your question? How to linearize the product of a binary and a non-negative continuous variable?

If you really want fewer constraints, you can instead impose the nonlinear constraints $v_{itk}=u_{it}x_{itk}$ or omit these constraints and just replace $v_{itk}$ throughout the rest of your model.

It looks like You want to enforce for all $i,t,k$:
$$
x_{itk}=1 \implies v_{itk} = u_{it} \quad  
$$
and
$$
x_{itk}=0 \implies v_{itk} =0
$$
You can get rid of the big-M as follows:
\begin{align}
x_{itk} + u_{it} - 1 &\le v_{itk} \le u_{it} \quad &\forall i,t,k\\
0 &\le v_{itk} \le x_{itk} \quad &\forall i,t,k\\
\end{align}
To be more precise, it is equivalent to OP's formulation with $M=1$ from the first constraint, and $M=0$ from the second constraint.
